# Excel formula if any cell in a range has a value get the value of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table

```
     A   B
1    3   Val1
2    2   Val2
3    2   Val3
4    1   Val1
5    5   Val3
```

Can anybody help me with a formula to sum cell values from the A column grouped by values of the B column

So it should return Val1 = 4 another formula for Val=2 another for Val3 =7

I Have the following but it is very ugly:

```
=IF(B1="Val1";A1)+IF(B2="Val1";A2)+IF(B3="Val1";A3)+IF(B4="Val1";A4)+IF(B5="Val1";A5)
```

Comment: **Consider using a Pivot Table.**

Comment: The [SUMIF function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010062465.aspx) should handle this. If you want to group two or more together like *Val1* and *Val4*, then the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/SUMIFS-function-9dd6179e-cced-41dd-ac38-08fdf5b929e5?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use this formula for each Valx:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B5,"Val1",A1:A5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUMIF` as in:

```
=SUMIF(B:B;"Val1";A:A)
```